# resourcePolicies was not found

Tags: google-compute-engine

I try to create VM from machine image but I get an error:
"The resource 'projects/my-project/regions/europe-west4/resourcePolicies/instance-1' was not found"
Actually instance-1 is located in europe-central2-a zone and i need to clone in europe-west4 zone.
Maybe there are nuances that are not indicated in the documentation. Has anyone encountered such a problem? Any suggestions?
Many thanks

The problem is that for a few days now I cannot run the installation due to lack of resources in my zone and I need to move it to another zone.
I tried redundancy but there are no resources for it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi `Evgeny Kim` expecting that you have already created a multi-regional image and this is not related to image availability I'm providing this answer. resourcePolicies are not supported by machine images follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-machine-images#instance_and_disk_properties_not_supported_by_machine_image) for  more information, instead of machine image you can create a boot disk and manually import it to your required location and relaunch the vm. follow this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-existing-image) for more information.

Comment: Yes it is multiregional

Comment: @EvgenyKim like I said above even though it's multi regional resourcePolicies feature is not supported by machine images, you need to create a new one when you are launching your vm and it involves many other steps. So, you can simply create a boot disk snapshot and create a boot image out of it then manually import this boot image to your desired location and relaunch the vm. This process I have already provided in the answer follow the second doc for your reference.